# How to show total amount after each transaction? How it can be stored?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

In database a have a table which stores transaction records for coins.

It looks like this:

| Id | UserId | ChangeInBalance | Created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 10 | 2021-09-08 12:00 |
| 2 | 5 | -6 | 2021-09-08 12:30 |
| 3 | 5 | -3 | 2021-09-08 12:35 |

I need to display these transactions in UI, with "Total amount" in each row like this:

| ChangeInBalance | Created | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2021-09-08 12:00 | 10 |
| -6 | 2021-09-08 12:30 | 4 |
| -3 | 2021-09-08 12:35 | 1 |

What is a common solution to this problem? To add "TotalAmount" column and calculate/store it on every table insert (I think concurrency problems can occur)? Or to calculate total amount in program code (since transactions are queried in pages, this shouldn't be a problem)? Or there is another better solution?

Thank you very much in advance!

I know that this is probably a duplicate question, but I had a hard time finding the needed answer, even though the problem is super widespread as I think (maybe I am bad at googling, sorry :( ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could used windowing functions like sum in a manner shown below

```
create table trx (Id    int, UserId int,    ChangeInBalance int,    Created datetime);
insert into trx values 
 (1,    5,  10, '2021-09-08 12:00')
,(2,    5,  -6, '2021-09-08 12:30')
,(3,    5,  -3, '2021-09-08 12:35');

select *, 
sum(changeinbalance) over (partition by userid order by created asc) as total
from trx
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

well you can use the sum analytic function as following

```
select UserId,ChangeInBalance,Created, Sum(ChangeInBalance) over (partition by UserId order by Created) as Total
from table name
```

see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#compute_a_cumulative_sum for more examples

you don't have to add the ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW as it is done automatically by some databases